# Can we add multiple conditions on left join in Mulesoft

Tags: join, left-join, mulesoft

Array 1:

```
[
        { 
            "name": "Abc", 
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Pqr", 
            "address":"Pune",
            "phone":"91-1234985438",
            "id":456
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Abc",
            "address":"Delhi",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }
    ]
```

Array 2:

```
[
    { 
        "sid":123,
        "postalCode": "67890",
        "country": "USA",
        "sname": "tyu"
    }, 
    { 
        "sid":864,
        "postalCode": "54983",
        "country": "UK",
        "sname": "Pqr"
    }, 
    { 
        "sid":123,
        "postalCode": "27932",
        "country": "EU",
        "sname": "Uvg"
    }
]
```

Above we have to consider both ID and name, if either of the fields match as leftjoin then we have to consider them.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "address": "Mumbai",
    "phone": "91-1234567891",
    "id": 123,
    "sid": 123,
    "sname": "tyu",
    "postalCode": "27932",
    "country": "EU"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pqr",
    "address": "Pune",
    "phone": "91-1234985438",
    "id": 456,
    "sid": 864,
    "sname": "Pqr",
    "postalCode": "54983",
    "country": "UK"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "address": "Delhi",
    "phone": "91-1234567891",
    "id": 123,
    "sid": 123,
    "sname": "Uvg",
    "postalCode": "27932",
    "country": "EU"
  }
]
```

Dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var Array2reversed=Array2[-1 to 0] distinctBy ((item, index) -> item.sid)
var combine=leftJoin(Array1, Array2reversed, (Array1) -> Array1.name, (Array2) -> Array2.sname) map $
---
(leftJoin(combine, Array2reversed, (Array1) -> Array1.id, (Array2) -> Array2.sid)) 
    map {
        "name": $.l.name, 
        "address": $.l.address,
        "phone": $.l.phone,
        "id": $.l.id,
        "sid": $.r.sid,
        "postalCode": $.r.postalCode,
        "country": $.r.country
    }.
```

We have to consider name and sname as another condition in left join. I tried to give in function but I'm getting error and not able to join with multiple conditions in one join only.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

Apparently, the function (combine) you've used to perform first leftJoin doesn't produce the result in the expected format for the subsequent leftJoin, leading to the error. Given that a single join can't accommodate multiple conditions, a possible solution is to perform another join on the outcome of the previous join to address this situation.

```
%dw 2.0
var Array1 = [
        { 
            "name": "Abc", 
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Pqr", 
            "address":"Pune",
            "phone":"91-1234985438",
            "id":456
        }, 
        { 
            "name": "Abc",
            "address":"Delhi",
            "phone":"91-1234567891",
            "id":123
        }
    ]
var Array2 = [
    { 
        "sid":123,
        "postalCode": "67890",
        "country": "USA",
        "sname": "tyu"
    }, 
    { 
        "sid":864,
        "postalCode": "54983",
        "country": "UK",
        "sname": "Pqr"
    }, 
    { 
        "sid":123,
        "postalCode": "27932",
        "country": "EU",
        "sname": "Uvg"
    }
]
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var Array2reversed=Array2[-1 to 0] distinctBy ((item, index) -> item.sid)
var combine = leftJoin(Array1, Array2reversed, (Array1) -> Array1.name, (Array2) -> Array2.sname) map ((item, index) -> item.l ++ (item.r default {}))

---
(leftJoin(combine, Array2reversed, (Array1) -> Array1.id, (Array2) -> Array2.sid)) 
    map {
        "name": $.l.name, 
        "address": $.l.address,
        "phone": $.l.phone,
        "id": $.l.id,
        "sid": $.r.sid  default $.l.sid,
        "sname": $.r.sname  default $.l.sname,
        "postalCode": $.r.postalCode default $.l.postalCode,
        "country": $.r.country default $.l.country
    }
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "address": "Mumbai",
    "phone": "91-1234567891",
    "id": 123,
    "sid": 123,
    "sname": "Uvg",
    "postalCode": "27932",
    "country": "EU"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pqr",
    "address": "Pune",
    "phone": "91-1234985438",
    "id": 456,
    "sid": 864,
    "sname": "Pqr",
    "postalCode": "54983",
    "country": "UK"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "address": "Delhi",
    "phone": "91-1234567891",
    "id": 123,
    "sid": 123,
    "sname": "Uvg",
    "postalCode": "27932",
    "country": "EU"
  }
]
```